# List of people who liked the photo on Instagram

Tags: php, curl, echo

I just want to List of people who liked photos on instagram with php.
But the page looking blank. Here is my code:

```
    function Connect($url){
        $curl=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        $data=curl_exec($curl);
        echo curl_error($curl);
        return str_replace(array("\n","\t","\r"),null,$data);
    }
    $bag=Connect("https://www.instagram.com/p/BfnPaG-HYrq/liked_by/");
    preg_match_all('#<a class="_2g7d5 notranslate _o5iw8 " title="(.*?)" href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>#', $bag, $list);
    $like=$list[1];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($like); $i++) {
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li>";
echo $like[i];
echo "</li>";
echo "</ul>";
}
```

How can do it? Thank you

Comment: What debugging have you done?  What is the value of `$bag` after calling `Connect()`?  What is the value of `$list` after the `preg_match_all()`?  Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: I don't know any way that you can access any instagram page content directly using curl or any type of request.

Answer (score 0):

You should echo $data to see if you are getting the expected page.

You must be logged in to get the results.  Instagram likely uses cookies to determine if a user, (in this case CURL), is logged in.

You are not sending any cookies in your request.

You must first log in and save the cookies. Then do your "likes" request using the cookies from the log in.

In the unlikely event you are getting the correct page then dump $list.